# DO Spaces object is uploaded as 0 bytes if i check md5 before uploading

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, amazon-s3, backend, go-gin

I have written a backend with GoLang to upload files to my dospaces. I want to check my files integrity so i calculate md5sum of file both on backend server and client then i upload the file if it is same. This worked fine with mp4 and jpeg files but i have switched to HLS format and trying to upload .ts and .m3u8 files. The md5 check is fine but if it is enabled the files are uploaded as 0 bytes and if disabled they are fine i honestly can't understand why this is happening.

```
func upload(c *gin.Context) {
    lock := sync.Mutex{}
    lock.Lock()
    // single file
    file, err := c.FormFile("file")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("file: " + err.Error())
    }

    log.Println(file.Filename)

    s3Client := getS3Client()

    filePart, err := file.Open()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("file: " + err.Error())
    }

    //Copy the file in the hash interface and check for any error
    //Convert the bytes to a string
    hashMD5 := getMD5Hash(filePart)

    // If this if block is disabled files are uploaded fine
    if c.Request.Header.Get("Hash-MD5") != hashMD5 {
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, "Bad file.")
        return
    }

    object := s3.PutObjectInput{
        Bucket: aws.String("BUCKET_NAME"),
        Key:    aws.String(file.Filename),
        Body:   filePart,
        ACL:    aws.String("public-read"),
    }

    _, err = s3Client.PutObject(&object)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err.Error())
        c.String(http.StatusBadRequest, err.Error())
        return
    }

    c.String(http.StatusOK, file.Filename+" uploaded!")

    filePart.Close()
    lock.Unlock()
}
```

Comment: You probably need to rewind the file reader's "cursor", no? https://pkg.go.dev/io#Seeker